# Google Admob verification is getting failed Always

Tags: flutter, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad, firebase-admob

I have integrated Google Ad Mob in my flutter app. The Google AdMob is getting reject, by saying that this error:

**You already have a Google publisher account. Sign in to your existing account to access AdMob. Or close your other accounts and submit your application to create an account again**

[Exiting Account Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GklPW.png)

Also getting this email after this review. I have never created any account on Admob with email starting with Utta....@gmail.com

[rejection email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6aGJ.png)

Please someone help me, its getting frustated. There is no direct help from Google or contact. I searched a lot. but none of the solutions working. I am trying this to solve since 1 month. I would really appreciate your help. Thanks in Advance.

I searched all the related solutions on stackoverflow. Also search on google forum. But none of them are working.

Comment: Facing same problem. Did you fix it?